# Proverbs 5:2-3 - Does the LXX preserve a dropped line or make an editorial addition?

Tags: proverbs, masoretic-text, lxx

The Masoretic Text and NRSV versions of the opening verses of Proverbs 5 are as follows (the MT follows the *Aleppo Codex* and is taken from the [Mechon-Mamre website](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2805.htm)):

| MT | NRSV |
| --- | --- |
| א בְּ֭נִי לְחָכְמָתִ֣י הַקְשִׁ֑יבָה לִ֝תְבֽוּנָתִ֗י הַט־אָזְנֶֽךָ׃ | 1 My child, be attentive to my wisdom; incline your ear to my understanding, |
| ב לִשְׁמֹ֥ר מְזִמּ֑וֹת וְ֝דַ֗עַת שְׂפָתֶ֥יךָ יִנְצֹֽרוּ׃ | 2 so that you may hold on to prudence, and your lips may guard knowledge. |
| ג כִּ֤י נֹ֣פֶת תִּ֭טֹּפְנָה שִׂפְתֵ֣י זָרָ֑ה וְחָלָ֖ק מִשֶּׁ֣מֶן חִכָּֽהּ׃ | 3 For the lips of a loose woman drip honey, and her speech is smoother than oil; |

Note the sudden, non-introduced (or is it – *vide infra*) description of the 'loose woman' in v. 3.

However, the text of the NJB is rather different, adding an extra 'line' at the end of v. 2 (emphasis added by me):

| NJB |
| --- |
| 1 My son, pay attention to my wisdom, listen carefully to what I know; |
| 2 so that you may preserve discretion and your lips may guard knowledge. ***Take no notice of a loose-living woman,*** |
| 3 for the lips of the adulteress drip with honey, her palate is more unctuous than oil, |

A footnote to the "Study Edition" of the NJB explains that this extra text follows the LXX, `μὴ πρόσεχε φαύλῃ γυναικί` (as per Ralph Hancock's transcription of *Codex Alexandrinus*).

So, my question is this: Does the LXX preserve text that was accidentally 'dropped' by scribal error, either by the Masoretes (highly unlikely) or by those who wrote the MSS from which they worked? Or did the translators of the LXX make a deliberate, 'editorial addition', to make the transition (from what is now v.2 to v. 3) smoother?

*Note that the reference to 'lips' in the (MT) version of v. 2 may be sufficient to link it with the following text, even without the LXX 'addition'.*

Is there any other textual evidence for this extra line? (Qumran MSS? Targumim? Peshitta? Other Hebrew MSS?)

Comment: This is my first post on this site. I hope it is (mostly) OK ... but I can't work out how to format the Hebrew text as right-to-left. If someone can advise (or edit), I would appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics! While table formatting may look better, it is not accessible for users with visual disabilities. Please see [Standard format for biblical quotations](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3794/standard-format-for-biblical-quotations). You may also find [How do I write an accessible Stack Exchange post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394687/how-do-i-write-an-accessible-stack-exchange-post) useful.

Comment: @AdrianMole (1) I would suggest stacking the MT/NRSV together. (2) While I have not typed in Hebrew, I have never had a problem copy/pasting in Hebrew into the editor. You could try using SE's https://stackedit.io/ as a preliminary editor to test out formatting.

Comment: @AdrianMole—Ultimately, you are not required to adhere to any particular formatting. Format your posts — because they are **yours** — at your discretion. Personally, I like how you used the table to compare the texts; I feel that is a fitting use of the table.